# Sitefinity 4.3 A/B Testing

Tags: sitefinity-4

I am using Sitefinity 4.3 for my organisation's site.

We have a home page and on it we are showing our Portfolio slider and it has Image, Text and Description.

The portfolio details are in the database. How should I go about doing A/B testing for this section as if we create another page the source will also be in the database.

Please guide how to approach A/B testing in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Google Experiments are an easy way to do this. There is a blog post on Telerik's site that highlights it (although, the blog is using 5.x)

http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/grisha-karanikolovs-blog/2013/04/12/a-b-and-multivariate-testing-with-sitefinity-cms-and-google-experiments